# Xkb: How to increase the number of KeySyms in the client map of an XkbDescRec keyboard description?

Tags: keyboard, x11, keycode

I'm trying to programmatically modify some of the properties of my xkb keyboard mapping in X11. In the `XkbClientMapRec` struct `map` member of the `XkbDescRec` struct, we have the following members:

```
typedef struct {                        /* Client Map */
  unsigned char      size_types;    /* # occupied entries in  types */
  unsigned char      num_types;     /* # entries in types */
  XkbKeyTypePtr      types;         /* vector of key types used by this keymap */
  unsigned short     size_syms;     /* length of the syms array */
  unsigned short     num_syms;      /* # entries in syms */
  KeySym *           syms;          /* linear 2d tables of keysyms, 1 per key */
  XkbSymMapPtr       key_sym_map;   /* 1 per keycode, maps keycode to syms */
  unsigned char *    modmap;        /* 1 per keycode, real mods bound to key */
} XkbClientMapRec, *XkbClientMapPtr;
```

Then, we have the XkbSymMapRec struct, here:

```
#define XkbNumKbdGroups            4
#define XkbMaxKbdGroup            (XkbNumKbdGroups-1)
typedef struct {                      /* map to keysyms for a single keycode */
  unsigned char     kt_index[XkbNumKbdGroups]; /* key type index for each group */
  unsigned char     group_info;       /* # of groups and out of range group handling */
  unsigned char     width;            /* max # of shift levels for key */
  unsigned short    offset;           /* index to keysym table in  syms array */
} XkbSymMapRec, *XkbSymMapPtr;
```

The `KeySym * syms` array in the `XkbClientMapRec` array is of course just an array of `KeySym`s (actually, an array of 2D arrays) as defined in `keysymdefs.h`.

Anyways, what I'm wondering here is how to add completely new `KeySym`s to that `syms` array. Basically I want to completely change the mapping for one of the key codes on my keyboard, and the KeySym that I want to equate is with isn't typically in the `KeySym`s array. Reassigning a keycode to an existing and defined set of `KeySym`s is easy - for example, if I wanted keycode 45 to do the same thing as keycode 63, I'd do this:

```
XkbDescPtr desc = XkbGetKeyboard( curr_display, XkbAllComponentsMask, XkbUseCoreKbd );
XkbSymMapRec * client_map = desc->map;
client_map->key_sym_map[ 45 ] = client_map->key_sym_map[ 23 ];
XkbMapChangesRec changes;
changes.changed = XkbKeySymsMask;
changes.first_key_sym = 45;
changes.num_key_syms = 1;
XkbChangeMap( curr_display, desc, &changes );
```

This works, but it isn't what I want. I want to create completely new `KeySym` entries in `client_map->sym` and assign `client_map->key_sym_map[ 45 ]->kt_index[ 0..n ]` to those new entries. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible? The XbkMapChangesRec struct doesn't have any way of stipulating that the `KeySym * syms` array has been reallocated to something larger. The best that it has is `XkbKeySymsMask` which is ONLY for changes to `key_sym_map`.

Any ideas?