# Parse Xkb layout file

Tags: c++, linux, xorg

For a project I'm working on I need to open *Xkb layout files* * and store the key info in memory. That is; storing which keysym each key is mapped to. Does anybody know an API in C++ domain that gets that done? I found [this](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor/blob/master/ParseXKB.py), but that's Python.

#### Example

Considering the first few lines of layout, English (US) ...

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    name[Group1]= "English (US)";

    key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
    key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
```

... I would like to store that for the layout "English (US)", key TLDE is holding 'grave' and 'asciitilde', key AE01 is holding '1' and 'exclam' and key AE02 is holding 'at'.

* In Ubuntu, Xkb layout files are stored in: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very much you'll find a C++ library to parse that file.  Your best bet would be a C function somewhere in the xorg code.  But are you sure that's what you want to do?  If you want to know how the keys are currently defined in the running server, you might be better off interrogating the server.  Surely X has a function that enumerates the keyboard definition?

Comment: Hm.. Yes, obtaining the current layout would be ok aswell (I would just have to load every layout once :)). However, I couldn't tell which function does that, any idea?

Comment: I found a function that does that, `XkbGetKeyboard()`. This question has a nice example on how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661998/xkb-how-to-increase-the-number-of-keysyms-in-the-client-map-of-an-xkbdescrec-ke